# HSQL and DBUnit - The given schema 'SA' does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, hsqldb, dbunit

I try to write some unit tests with DBUnit. I want to use the in-memory database HSQL.
First in my Hibernate properties I use

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

to create the tables from my entities.

Then I configure my datasource like this (file test-hibernate-config.xml):

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.syntax_ora=true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>SA</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value></value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then my test class look like this:

```
@Override
protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
  return new String[] {"batch-spring-daos.xml", 
                      "test-hibernate-config.xml", 
                      "batch-spring-transactionManager.xml"};
}

public void setLivraisonDAO(ILivraisonDAO livraisonDAO) {
  this.livraisonDAO = livraisonDAO;
}

@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
@InsertDBUnitData(dataLocations={ "data/data_release" } )
public void shouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionWhenReleaseDoesntExists(){
  livraisonDAO.getAllLivraisons("1");
}

@Test
@InsertDBUnitData(dataLocations={ "data/data_release", "data/data_livraison"} )
public void shouldRetrieveOneRelease(){
  List<LivraisonEntity> allLivraisons = livraisonDAO.getAllLivraisons("2.5.0.0");
  assertTrue(!allLivraisons.isEmpty());
}
```

The file batch-spring-dao.xml and batch-spring-transactionManager.xml are those that I use in my application.

But when I try to run my test, I got those logs:

```
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,349] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:348 : Unsuccessful: alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F18F2A1C61A foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,349] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:349 : a FOREIGN KEY constraint already exists on the set of columns: FK7327F18F2A1C61A in statement [alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F18F2A1C61A foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE]
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,349] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:348 : Unsuccessful: alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F1848CCEB7F foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,364] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:349 : a FOREIGN KEY constraint already exists on the set of columns: FK7327F1848CCEB7F in statement [alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F1848CCEB7F foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE]
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,364] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:348 : Unsuccessful: alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F18DAE59D90 foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,364] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:349 : a FOREIGN KEY constraint already exists on the set of columns: FK7327F18DAE59D90 in statement [alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F18DAE59D90 foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE]
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,364] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:348 : Unsuccessful: alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F188951F74F foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,364] ERROR [main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create:349 : a FOREIGN KEY constraint already exists on the set of columns: FK7327F188951F74F in statement [alter table IMPACTPARAMDEFECT add constraint FK7327F188951F74F foreign key (IDPARAMETRAGE) references PARAMETRAGE]
3 nov. 2014 10:06:41 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@67966796] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,442] INFO  [main] ch.gma.commons.test.AbstractGmaTest.insertData:183 : insertData - *** Inserting test data : file path = data/data_release, schema = ***
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,458] WARN  [main] org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection.validateSchema:195 : The given schema 'SA' does not exist.
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,489] ERROR [main] org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData:286 : Table 'RELEASE' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[], _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]

[2014-11-03 10:06:41,489] INFO  [main] ch.gma.commons.test.AbstractGmaTest.insertData:189 : insertData - *** Finished inserting test data ***
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,489] INFO  [main] ch.gma.commons.test.AbstractGmaTest.insertData:183 : insertData - *** Inserting test data : file path = data/data_release, schema = ***
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,489] WARN  [main] org.dbunit.database.DatabaseConnection.validateSchema:195 : The given schema 'SA' does not exist.
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,505] ERROR [main] org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData:286 : Table 'RELEASE' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[], _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]
[2014-11-03 10:06:41,505] INFO  [main] ch.gma.commons.test.AbstractGmaTest.insertData:189 : insertData - *** Finished inserting test data ***
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of dbunit do you use?

Comment: I use the DBUnit 2.4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer by myself.

I had to specify the PUBLIC schema to be used.

I add this property:

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</prop>
```

and to my unit tests, I changed the annotation:

```
@InsertDBUnitData(dataLocations={ "data/data_release" } )
```

to

```
@InsertDBUnitData(dataLocations={ "data/data_release" }, schema="PUBLIC")
```

And my tests work!

Hope this can help somebody!